# Show that the function $f(x)=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{\sin(x)}\right)}{x^2}\in\mathcal C^2([-1,1])$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that $$f(x)=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{\sin(x)}\right)}{x^2}$$ is $\mathcal C^2([-1,1])$. The only problem is in $0$, but I proved that $$f(x)=-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{3}{20}x^2+o(x^2)$$
is it enough ?

Comment: $f$ is not defined at $0$

Comment: Well, the prolongement of $f$ if you prefer !

Comment: In other words, show that $f$ can be defined at $0$ so that the resulting function is $C^2([-1,1]).$

Comment: why is it enough ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch: Let $g(x) = \arctan x/ \sin x.$ Then $g$ has a removable singularity at $0$ if we set $g(0)=1.$ In fact the extended $g$ is real analytic and even near $0.$ Because compositions of real analytic functions are real analytic, $\ln (g(x))$ is real analytic and even near $0$ as well. An even real analytic function has only even powers of $x$ in its power series expansion about $0,$ so $\ln (g(x)) = a_0 + a_2x^2 +a_4x^4 + \cdots$ near $0.$ Since $a_0 = 0,$ we get $\ln(g(x))/x^2 = a_2 + a_4x^2 + \cdots$ near $0.$ So in fact $\ln(g(x))/x^2$ is real analytic near $0,$ hence $C^\infty$ there.